# Is installing an game through steam safer (to the computer configuration) than installing it stand-alone?

Tags: steam

Since I use my computer for development, I actively avoid gaming on it (because of bad experiences with games screwing up configuration). But I got curious to see some games running on PC (Skyrim comes to mind, with all those cool mods), instead of PS3.

Is installing a game through Steam more "sandboxed" that a stand-alone installation - in regards to changes in preferences, registry, etc, etc?

Comment: "Is installing a game through Steam more "sandboxed" that a stand-alone installation" - Nope.

Comment: No. It affects your directories, registry, and preferences the same way. Only the pathing & launching is via Steam.

Comment: Steam is DRM.  The game's installation is handled by Steam.  This means  uninstalling it, is just a matter of, removing the data files from your HDD.  The majority time spent installing something with a standalone installers (of any application), is extracting and copying the files to your system, and installing require libaries like Visual C++, most applications do not make any changes to the registry.  Steam skips the copying and extraction step, and replaces it with a single step of downloading the data file directly.

Comment: The end result is the same, data files on your HDD, and the required library files are installed.  User configuration files, that determine the settings the application will use, is normally stored in the user's directory on Windows Vista and above.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I searched the site and googled but found none addressing this doubt.

Comment: @Ramhound So, if I'm concerned with that, I need to use virtualization?

Comment: Programs like Sandboxie would acomplish what you want.  If it works with Steam and your entire library I have no idea.  Virtualization wouldn't acomplish your goals of actually being able to Steam and your library in most cases.

Comment: My suggestion with regards to sandboxie is because I truely believe that's the future of computing, either or virtualization like on the Xbox One.  Although sandboxes have the advantage of only needing large amounts storage, instead of additional compute cycles.  It also allows your sandbox to be made aware of the dependencies that exist on the system without being able to add dependencies itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Steam is something extra that has to run in addition to the game, it does not make the game less complex to the computer.

If you're concerned about negatively affecting a development computer, you could try dual-booting. Virtualization typically does not work well with games that require 3D acceleration of any sort.